# Looking for group $G$ such that $G$ nilpotent, $N \leq G$, $N \cap Z(G) = \{1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ nilpotent, $N \leq G$, $N \cap Z(G) = \{1\}$. Note that it is a common exercise to show that if we add the assumption t hat $N \triangleleft G$ then $N \cap Z(G) \neq 1$. So I'm really looking for a counter example! I've been thinking for awhile now but can't think of anything. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: There is a non-abelian group of order 27 and of exponent 3 (that is, $x^3=1$ for all $x\in G$). So the subgroup generated by any non-central element has the property you're after (and such an element/subgroup exists). Note that this group is nilpotent as has prime-power order.

Comment: Easier, let $G$ be dihedral of order $8$, and $N$ of order $2$, generated by a reflection.